# Rails form creates instance but doesn't fill it with data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Before I get into this: Yes, I am aware that this is not a secure way to store usernames and passwords.

Moving on, I'm trying to set up a system that will allow me to create accounts with a username, a password, and a value, and then display each account's username and value. I've gotten to the point where it will create a new template, for lack of a better word, to display the username and value, but nothing is actually being displayed. My controller:

```
class TestController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @accounts = Account.all
  end

  def new
    @account = Account.new
  end

  private def account_params
    params.require(:account).permit(:username).permit(:password)
  end

  def create
    @account = Account.new(account_params)
    if @account.save
      redirect_to '/index'
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

And my form:

```
<%= form_for(@account) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <h3>Username:</h3>
    <%= f.text_area :username %><br>
    <h3>Password:</h3>
    <%= f.text_area :password %>
  </div>
  <div class="action">
    <%= f.submit "Create" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Finally, my migration file:

```
class CreateAccounts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :accounts do |t|
      t.string :username
      t.string :password
      t.integer :value
    end
  end
end
```

Actual code that displays each account:

```
<% @accounts.each do |t|  %>
  <div class="accountbox">
    <strong>Username:</strong><%= t.username  %><br>
    <br>
    <strong>Value:</strong> <%= t.value  %><br>
  </div>
<% end  %>
```

Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'index' => 'test#index'
  get 'new' => 'test#new'

  post 'accounts' => 'test#create'
end
```

Oh, and I should note that data in `db/seed.rb` does display properly, it's just the accounts created that don't function.

Comment: So, you can submit the form with the data, but it's not being saved? Or you can't even get the form to show up?

Comment: The form shows up and I can submit without issue, but when I try and list all accounts it creates the box where the data should be but no data displays.

Comment: Okay, so you need to show us that HTML ERB code.

Comment: Added to original post.

Comment: How are you setting `value` ?  And just to make sure, this code you added, it is in the accounts `index.html.erb` page?  Also, why is your create method under the `private` marker, can you verify that method is actually receiving the data?

Comment: I'm not, its meant to be 0 by default(I guess it would actually be null in this case, but would that keep each username from being displayed)? And yes, it is in index.html.erb.

Comment: `redirect_to '/index'` seems to be changed to `redirect_to index_url` where `index_url` depends on your routes

Comment: If you put this line in your create method `puts "ACCOUNT: #{@account}"` underneath the first line where you set the `@account` variable, do you see any output in the terminal when sending a new form?

Comment: @RockwellRice Nope, no output that I can see. Oh, and I think you might have seen my comment before I deleted it, but I accidentally added an extra character, that's what caused the syntax error.

Comment: Ok, can you try to move the `create` method above the private tag and see if that makes a difference?

Comment: Still nothing. I'll edit in the routes to the original post, maybe the issue is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think part of the issue here is the `account_parameters` whitelisting.

`permit(*filters)` takes a collection of symbols representing the permitted parameters. It should look like `permit(:username, :password)`. By calling `permit` on the result of `permit`, I believe this code is filtering down to `:username`, and then from that list trying to pull out `:password`, losing both values in the process.

Try changing that function to:

```rb
private def account_params
  params.require(:account).permit(:username, :password)
end
```

[Permit docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit)